# Create all possible Map<String, List<String>> from a List<String>

Tags: list, lambda, collections, java-8, hashmap

From a given `List<String>` I want to generate all possible `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Example:
Input:

```
List<String> asianCountries = Arrays.asList("India", "China", "Japan", "Korea");
```

Output: Create a `Map<String, List<String>>:`

```
{
  India=[India, China, Japan, Korea],    
  China=[India, China, Japan, Korea],   
  Korea=[India, China, Japan, Korea], 
  Japan=[India, China, Japan, Korea]
};
```

I want to create a method which would take a List and generate a Map> as above so that I can operate and do a putAll on a Map for any number of such Lists.

Is there any elegant way to do it in Java8+

Comment: But why would you do that?

Comment: Just bored, I guess that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
asianCountries.stream().collect(toMap(Function.identity(),v->asianCountries));
```